# Dependency issues when installing devtools in R

Tags: r, devtools

I haven't been able to install devtools in R, and I've seen other posts with similar issues but nothing with the exact same error, and none of those solutions have worked for me. When I input install.packages('devtools') I get this:

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/maggi/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘fs’, ‘processx’, ‘usethis’, ‘callr’, ‘rcmdcheck’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions
  are later:
          binary source needs_compilation
fs         1.2.7  1.3.1              TRUE
processx   3.3.0  3.4.1              TRUE
usethis    1.5.0  1.5.1             FALSE
callr      3.2.0  3.3.1             FALSE
rcmdcheck  1.3.1  1.3.3             FALSE
devtools   2.0.2  2.1.0             FALSE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/fs_1.2.7.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 973247 bytes (950 KB)
downloaded 950 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/processx_3.3.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 246452 bytes (240 KB)
downloaded 240 KB

package ‘fs’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘processx’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\maggi\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpaoJOLV\downloaded_packages
installing the source packages ‘usethis’, ‘callr’, ‘rcmdcheck’, ‘devtools’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/usethis_1.5.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 620225 bytes (605 KB)
downloaded 605 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/callr_3.3.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 94264 bytes (92 KB)
downloaded 92 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rcmdcheck_1.3.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 45380 bytes (44 KB)
downloaded 44 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/devtools_2.1.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 378899 bytes (370 KB)
downloaded 370 KB

* installing *source* package 'usethis' ...
** package 'usethis' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'fs' 1.2.7 is being loaded, but >= 1.3.0 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'usethis'
* removing 'C:/Users/maggi/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/usethis'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\maggi\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\maggi\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpaoJOLV/downloaded_packages/usethis_1.5.1.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘usethis’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'callr' ...
** package 'callr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'processx' 3.3.0 is being loaded, but >= 3.4.0 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'callr'
* removing 'C:/Users/maggi/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/callr'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\maggi\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\maggi\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpaoJOLV/downloaded_packages/callr_3.3.1.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘callr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'callr' is not available for package 'rcmdcheck'
* removing 'C:/Users/maggi/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/rcmdcheck'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\maggi\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\maggi\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpaoJOLV/downloaded_packages/rcmdcheck_1.3.3.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rcmdcheck’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'usethis', 'callr', 'rcmdcheck' are not available for package 'devtools'
* removing 'C:/Users/maggi/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/devtools'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\maggi\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\maggi\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpaoJOLV/downloaded_packages/devtools_2.1.0.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\maggi\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpaoJOLV\downloaded_packages’
```

I think it's unable to install some of the dependencies? I'm seeing things like "namespace 'processx' 3.3.0 is being loaded, but >= 3.4.0 is required" a few times. Sorry, I'm a complete coding amateur but if any of you have seen this issue before or know what to do, I'd greatly appreciate it. I'm on Windows, if that's helpful.

Comment: Your version of R (3.4) is quite old - the current version is 3.6.1. The errors indicate that newer versions of some packages are required. Upgrade your R installation, update existing packages, then try again.

Comment: The two packages that failed (`fs` and `processx`) both had a source package available that satisfied the minimum version requirements in the errors listed here. Have you tried `type="source"` when you install them?

Comment: You may need to install [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) to be able to install packages from source on Windows.

Comment: @neilfws You were completely right, I had downloaded the latest version of R but was running an older one. Thank you for your help!!